# Encode/Decode struct object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, struct

I am studying this wavefront obj loader example: https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff/tree/master/Wavefront%20OBJ%20Loader

And in order to improve object loading speed - I decided to encode loaded objects as NSValue and then store in Core data. Later, when corresponding object needs to be shown again - I fetch from database necessary nsvalue and unarchieve it.

It's all working, but problem is - it's not as fast I hoped it would be.

One of the reasons - because, in that example are used struct objects.

I was not successful to encode/decode them, so I used NSMutableArray, in which I write all struct data, and later - I iterate through it to put back values to struct object.

For example, there is struct:

```
typedef struct {
GLfloat x;
GLfloat y;
GLfloat z;
} Vertex3D;
```

It is then defined:

```
typedef Vertex3D Vector3D;
```

But in OpenGLWaveFrontObject class it is used like this:

```
Vector3D *vertexNormals;
```

how can I encode/decode struct like this?

I've tried like this:

```
[coder encodeObject:[NSValue value:&vertexNormals withObjCType:@encode(Vector3D)] forKey:@"vertexNormals"];
```

or like this:

```
[coder encodeObject:[NSValue value:&vertexNormals withObjCType:@encode(Vector3D[30])] forKey:@"vertexNormals"];
```

but its not working - if successfully encoded, then when decoding - values are incorrect.

example, how I put back in array of struct necessary values:

```
    vertices = malloc(sizeof(Vertex3D) *  [verticesArray count]);

    for(int i = 0; i < [verticesArray count]; i++)
    {            
        vertices[i].x = [[[verticesArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

        vertices[i].y = [[[verticesArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

        vertices[i].z = [[[verticesArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    }
```

this works, but I have few more struct arrays and in case arrays are big - this becomes a big issue.

**EDIT:**

Using **Amin Negm-Awad** provided answer:

If I simply change NSArchiver to NSKeyedArchiver - it throws error:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver encodeArrayOfObjCType:count:at:]: unsupported type "{?=fff}]" for array encoding'
```

When I try:

```
NSValue *encapsulated = [NSValue valueWithBytes:vertexNormals objCType:@encode(Vertex3D[3])]; 
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:encapsulated]; 
[coder encodeObject:data forKey:@"vertexNormals"];
```

And vertexNormals were created:

```
vertexNormals = calloc(3, sizeof(Vector3D));
```

and filled with similar data You provided.

**EDIT 2:**

Using updated answer which Amin Negm-Awad provided,

I was successfully able to store struct object as NSData and encode it, and after that - decode it. It works!

example, so that it might help some one else too:

```
//Encode
NSData *verticesData = [NSData dataWithBytes:vertices length:numberOfVertices * sizeof(Vector3D)];

[coder encodeObject:verticesData forKey:@"vertices"];


//Decode
vertices = malloc(sizeof(Vertex3D) * numberOfVertices);

NSData *verticesData = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"vertices"];

[verticesData getBytes:vertices length:sizeof(Vertex3D) *  numberOfVertices];
```

where Vertex3D was a struct:

```
typedef struct {
GLfloat x;
GLfloat y;
GLfloat z;
} Vertex3D;
```

and used as a struct array (I don't know how it is really called):

```
Vertex3D *vertices;
```

Unfortunately I was not able to store texture data. I can encode and decode, but decoded data are always randomly bizarre.

I am declaring it in this way:

```
GLfloat *textureCoords;
```

And I Encoded/Decoded in this way:

```
//Encode
NSData *textureCoordsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:textureCoords length:valuesPerCoord * numberOfVertices];

[coder encodeObject:textureCoordsData forKey:@"textureCoords"];

//Decode
textureCoords = malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * valuesPerCoord * numberOfVertices);

NSData *textureCoordsData = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"textureCoords"];

[textureCoordsData getBytes:textureCoords length:valuesPerCoord * numberOfVertices];
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you want to encode a single struct or an array of that structs? What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Array of structs. Not working - as - if successfully encoded, then when decoded are randomly incorrect values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: If the array has variable length, it is simply not possible to use NSValue. This is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000174-BAJJHDEG):

> The type you specify must be of constant length. You cannot store C
>   strings, variable-length arrays and structures, and other data types
>   of indeterminate length in an NSValue—you should use NSString or
>   NSData objects for these types.

So you should really take into account to use NSData instead.

But, if you want to use NSValue (because you have a constant-length array):

Both of your approaches has an extra indirection. The first one has the wrong type, too. What should work:

```
// Create some data
Vertex3D *cArray = malloc(30 * sizeof(Vertex3D));
NSInteger i;
for (i=0; i<30; i++)
{
   cArray[i].x = i;
   cArray[i].y = 9811;
   cArray[i].z = 29-i;
}
NSLog(@"%p", cArray);

// Encapsulate that in a value
// Have a look at the parameters
NSValue *encapsulated = [NSValue valueWithBytes:cArray objCType:@encode(Vertex3D[30])];

// Put it through a coder and store the coded data on disk
NSData *data = [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:encapsulated];
[data writeToFile:[@"~/Desktop/valueTest" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically:YES];
// Out is done here

// from disk
data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[@"~/Desktop/valueTest" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
encapsulated = [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

Vertex3D *cArray2 = malloc(30 * sizeof(Vertex3D));
[encapsulated getValue:cArray2];
for (i=0; i<30; i++)
{
   NSLog(@"%f %f %f", cArray[i].x, cArray[i].y, cArray[i].z);
}
NSLog(@"%p", cArray2);
```

This works in my test code

**Update** because of the problem with keyed achieving:
To store the c array in an instance of NSData instead of an instance of NSValue do this instead

After

```
NSLog(@"%p", cArray);
```

change the code to

```
// Convert to an NSData instance
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cArray length:lengthInBytes];
[data writeToFile:[@"~/Desktop/valueTest" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically:YES];
// Out is done here

// from disk
data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[@"~/Desktop/valueTest" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
Vertex3D *cArray2 = malloc(lengthInBytes);
[data getBytes:cArray2 length:lengthInBytes];
```

until

```
for (i=0; i<30; i++)
```

Comment: It shows to me "Use of undeclared identifier 'NSArchiver'" 

And it doesn't work with NSKeyedArchiver (shows - -[NSKeyedArchiver encodeValueOfObjCType:at:]: array count is missing or zero')

I read that NSArchiver is older than NSKeyedArchiver, so - could it be possible that sdk 4.6 (iOS6.1) doesn't support it anymore?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I tested that code on Mac OS. But it is not important, how you encode/decode it. This is only the test code around (and probably your instance is deep in the object graph, so your code looks different anyway). Simply change NSArchiver to NSKeyedArchiver and NSUnarchiver to NSKeyedUnarchiver. But this is not important. Important is, that there is *no extra indirection* to the parameter valueWithBytes:. Look at the lines following the comment: "Encapsulate that in a value".

Comment: Oh, yes, keyed archiver does not support this. I did not know that. So use NSData instead.

Comment: Please see my updated question. Thanks to You I was able to encode/decode struct arrays, but I still need one thing - encode/decode CGFloat array? (or how that is called). See EDIT 2. Thank You for Your help so far!!!

Comment: Ok, anyway - if You cannot help me further - You still helped me with original problem, So I am marking it as accepted and +1 for helping out! Thanks again!